# Items in List not showing in inspector

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I have a function that looks for a "Tile" on a certain position, adds that to a list and then returns that list to a different list. However, no list items are displayed in the inspector when the game runs, even tho when i use debugging or Debug.Log, it shows the list contains the correct "Tile".

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PieceController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Location managing")]
    public Tile currentTile;
    public Vector3 currentTilePos;

    [Header("Move making")]
    public Piece pieceType;
    public List<Tile> validTiles = new List<Tile>();

    private TileSelector tileSelector;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        tileSelector = GameObject.Find("GameController").GetComponent<TileSelector>();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        currentTilePos = currentTile.GetComponent<Tile>().positionTop;
        validTiles = CalculateValidTiles();

        Debug.Log("Valid tiles: " + validTiles.ToString());
    }

    public List<Tile> CalculateValidTiles()
    {
        float tileLength = pieceType.tileLength;
        List<Tile> tiles = new List<Tile>();

        foreach (LegalMove move in pieceType.moves)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Calculating move: " + move.name);

            Vector3 legalPosition;
            Vector3 originPosition = transform.position;

            legalPosition = new Vector3(originPosition.x + move.tilesPositiveX, originPosition.y, originPosition.z + move.tilesPositiveZ);

            //Debug.Log("Legal position: " + legalPosition.ToString());

            Ray ray = new Ray(legalPosition, Vector3.down);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1.5f))
            {
                Debug.Log("Hit: " + hit.collider.gameObject.name);

                if (hit.collider.gameObject.tag == "piece" && !validTiles.Contains(hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>()))
                {
                    tiles.Add(hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>());

                    //Debug.Log("Added tile: " + hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<Tile>().tile);
                }
            }
        }

        Debug.Log("Tiles calculated: " + tiles.ToString());


        return tiles;
    }

}
```

I can't figure out why it won't show the items in the inspector. I've tried updating my editor version to 2021.3.14f1, and adding items to the "validTiles" list directly, instead of using a return.

Comment: In general: don't create a new `List` every frame, rather keep the same list and only `Clear` it, this would save quite some GC work

Comment: You should have posted the your code of `class Tile` too. Probably, and I am assuming now, you should add `[Serializable]` before `public class Time {}`, as I guess it is not a MonoBehouvior but just deriving from `class Object`. For any class to show up in the inspector they have to be serialable.